# jekyll -v with WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I wanna use the HPSTR jekyll theme, when I did `jekyll serve`, terminal throw me errors:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find coffee-script-source-1.9.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:139:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:184:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:37:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Then I try to using `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I was told this:

`-bash: bundle: command not found`

Therefore I typed `bundle install` in the console, everything goes well, except, after bundle installed `jekyll -v` throw out things like this:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      pygments.rb (~> 0.6.0)
      redcarpet (~> 3.1)
      listen (~> 2.7)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
jekyll 2.5.3
```

How to clearing out unresolved specs?

I've tried `gem cleanup pygments.rb`, `gem cleanup redcarpet`, and `gem cleanup listen`. these commands runs good, but the result of `jekyll -v` was the same.

I even tried `bundle clean --force`, still got the same WARN.

anyone have any idea? thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
git clone git@github.com:mmistakes/hpstr-jekyll-theme.git
cd hpstr-jekyll-theme/
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve
```